# [hy000][mysql][odbc 3.51 driver]Cant connect to MYSQL server on 'mysql8.namesco.net' (10061)

Tags: mysql, ms-access, odbc

I'm having a right nightmare trying to link Microsoft Access to MySQL.

I have selected the ODBC 3.51 to connect to mysql on access

**Details required:**

TCP / IP - mysql8.namesco.net OR IP Address 
Named Pipe - BLANK
Username - **** 

Password - **** 
Port - 3306 (Default) 
Database name

After I enter the above details i'm prompted with the following error:

> Connection failed:[hy000][mysql][odbc 3.51 driver]Cant connect to MYSQL server on 'mysql8.names.net' (10061)
> /

I get the same error when I use ODBC 5.1 Driver:

> Connection failed:[hy000][mysql][odbc 5.1 driver]Cant connect to MYSQL server on 'mysql8.names.net' (10061)

I have no idea what i'm doing wrong!

any help to resolve this would be amazing!

Comment: if its a hosting server you need to log into your cpanel and add your external ip in the allowed ip range to connect the databases. also many hosting have standalone ip for accessing database. as below answer says raise ticket to your hosting support and ask for help

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping the MySQL server from your machine? Can you connect to MySQL from your machine with any other MySQL client?

Sometimes hosting companies like names.co.uk put their MySQL servers behind firewalls. You may need to consult their tech support if you need access from someplace outside their data center.

> Max Thorley: How do i ping? is it telnet IP address? I contacts names
>   to allow remote access. I gave them my public facing IP and IPv4
>   (which i believe is static)?? 
> This what I get with telnet
>   C:\Users\max.thorley>telnet 192.168.35.24 Connecting To
>   192.168.35.24...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed C:\Users\max.thorley>telnet mysql9.namesco.net
>   Connecting To mysql9.namesco.net...Could not open connection to the
>   host, on por t 23: Connect failed

Try `telnet mysql9.namesco.net 3306` to see if you can access the MySQL port. You probably can't. If you can't get to it you'll get a similar message to the ones you got with other `telnet` attempts.  That means your hosting service has firewalled the MySQL server. If you can get to it you'll get some gibberish that looks roughly like this:

```
 5.5.5-MySQL
            %\~)L%q? $p*}X!73:i%wmysql_native_password
```

You probably can't get to it. This is common hosting-service practice, because it's a shared server and it's not very hard to mount denial-of-service attacks against MySQL servers.  Again, you need to consult your tech support.

> if its a hosting server you need to log into your cpanel and add your
>   external ip in the allowed ip range to connect the databases. also
>   many hosting have standalone ip for accessing database. as below
>   answer says raise ticket to your hosting support and ask for help – 
>   krish KM

Comment: How do i ping? is it telnet IP address? I contacts names to allow remote access. I gave them my public facing IP and IPv4 (which i believe is static)??

<br>This what I get with telnet</br>

C:\Users\max.thorley>telnet 192.168.35.24
Connecting To 192.168.35.24...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23:
 Connect failed


C:\Users\max.thorley>telnet mysql9.namesco.net
Connecting To mysql9.namesco.net...Could not open connection to the host, on por
t 23: Connect failed